# custom style to a region of a flexible layout

Tags: views, panels

I want to use panel fields in views. So I created the flexible panel layout in custom layout. Added some style to it i.e rounded corner, fonts etc. 
But when I save the layout no style appears in preview mode, even the settings button is gone from the panels. So while using in views no style shows up.

[image: Here you can see the error, the button is not visible.] (settings button is not showing)

Comment: try to activated all the panels modules, It might help.

Comment: already done that.Any other suggestion??

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest recommended version 7.x-3.3.By the way when I add the custom style to panels in panel pages or nodes the style is showing up,but in case of panel fields in views it's not showing up? check  this node https://drupal.org/node/1386148 I think they have the same problem.